# How prove this $\int_{a}^{b}xf(x)dx\le\int_{a}^{b}xg(x)dx$

Tags: integral-inequality

let $f(x),g(x)$  is continuous on $[a,b]$,and such
$$\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt\ge\int_{a}^{x}g(t)dt,x\in[a,b)$$
and
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt=\int_{a}^{b}g(t)dt$$
show that:
$$\int_{a}^{b}xf(x)dx\le\int_{a}^{b}xg(x)dx$$

my try: we only prove this
$$\Longleftrightarrow \int_{a}^{b}x(f(x)-g(x))dx\le 0$$
if $[a,b]\subset (-\infty,0]$,then 
$x<0$ this is true.But other case I can't.Thank you

Comment: Integration by parts? One of the inequalities looks mixed up.

Comment: A change of variables from the negative case to the positive case also seems quite plausible, i.e. prove the negative $x$ case then change of variables from $x$ to $-x$ and use the previous result. Though, I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do this problem.

Comment: your example is not such second condition,Thank you

Comment: I see now, in my head I forgot the minus sign in integration by parts. The problem is formulated correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $F(x) = \int_{a}^{x}f(t)\,dt, G(x) = \int_{a}^{x}g(t)\,dt$ then we have $F(x) \geq G(x)$ for all $x \in [a, b)$ and $F(b) = G(b)$. Now we have $$\int_{a}^{b}xf(x)\,dx = bF(b) - aF(a) - \int_{a}^{b}F(x)\,dx = bF(b) - \int_{a}^{b}F(x)\,dx$$ and $$\int_{a}^{b}xg(x)\,dx = bG(b) - aG(a) - \int_{a}^{b}G(x)\,dx = bG(b) - \int_{a}^{b}G(x)\,dx$$ so that

$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}\int_{a}^{b}x\{f(x) - g(x)\}\,dx &= b\{F(b) - G(b)\} - \int_{a}^{b}\{F(x) - G(x)\}\,dx\\
&= -\int_{a}^{b}\{F(x) - G(x)\}\,dx \leq 0\end{aligned}$

Comment: nice, simple and clear.

Answer (score 6):

$$F (x) = \int_a^x (f-g)(x)\ dx \geq 0,\ F(a)=F(b)=0$$

$$\int_a^b x(f-g)(x)\ dx = x\int_a^x (f-g)(t)\ dt\ |_{x=a}^{x=b} - \int_a^b (1) [ \int_a^t (f-g )(s)\ ds\ ]\ dt $$
  $$  =  - \int_a^b F(t)\ dt \leq 0$$

Comment: You seem to use the more compact notation of leaving out the differential symbol $dx$ (unless really necessary) in your integrals. Makes the proof look more concise.(+1)